# How to express a textual definition using OWL/RDFS?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, rdfs

I have multiple classes. Those classes have multiple labels and a textual definition. While it is clear to me that I can use `rdfs:label` for names I am currently struggling with a suitable property for definitions.

I think that a *label* and a *definition* are different concepts and should not be expressed using the same property. Looking through the RDFS recommendation, I could not find a suitable property. I have seen that `rdfs:comment` is sometimes used - but I think a *comment* is different from a *definition*. Also, `rdfs:isDefinedBy` does not seem to be a suitable candidate. I could also not come up with a suitable candidate in OWL.

Why is there no `rdfs:definition`. What am I missing here?

Comment: The question is, why should there be another property? *"The `rdfs:comment` property is used to provide a human-readable description of a resource.

A textual comment helps clarify the meaning of RDF classes and properties. Such inline documentation complements the use of both formal techniques (Ontology and rule languages) and informal (prose documentation, examples, test cases). A variety of documentation forms can be combined to indicate the intended meaning of the classes and properties described in an RDF Schema. "*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AKSW said in his, uh, comment: `rdfs:comment` is intended for exactly that use.

I suppose the word “comment” here is used like it is in programming. The “human-readable definition” of a class or function is usually written in a *comment* on the function definition.

If you find `rdfs:comment` too broad, then `skos:definition` is a good alternative. It is one of the [documentation properties in SKOS](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-skos-reference-20090818/#notes), and the [SKOS Primer says](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/NOTE-skos-primer-20090818/#secdocumentation):

> `skos:definition` supplies a complete explanation of the intended meaning of a concept.

While SKOS is mostly known for its ability to define concept schemes, its documentation properties can be used on resources of any type. In fact, documenting an `owl:Class` is [one of the examples given](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-skos-reference-20090818/#L1879):

> In the example graph below, skos:definition has been used to provide a plain text definition for a resource of type owl:Class — this is consistent with the SKOS data model.
>
> ```
> <Protein> rdf:type owl:Class ;
>     skos:definition """A physical entity consisting of
>         a sequence of amino-acids; a protein monomer;
>         a single polypeptide chain. An example is the
>         EGFR protein."""@en .
> ```